# How can I get the VS Color Theme Editor to color my tabs properly?

Tags: windows-xp, tabs, visual-studio-2010, themes

In an application (Visual Studio 2010) the tabs of files that are opened in the editor are always brownisch, whatever Windows theme I use. There is a plugin for VS2010 (Visual Studio Color Theme Editor) that supports customization of theme colors, and it works except for tab coloring - anybody an idea? Windows XP.

Comment: I'd ask this question on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I wouldn't. This is hardly programming-related.

Comment: hardly programmming-related question, but you can find more Visual Studio 2010 users on stackoverflow.com ^^

Answer (score 1):

The [Productivity Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ProductivityPowerTools) for Visual Studio 2010 allow you to color code your tabs by project or regular expressions.

See [Tab Well 2010](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/document-well-2010-plus-hidden-options/) included in the power tools extensions.

Comment: I was going to suggest the exact same thing.  PPT is an excellent Visual Studio extension.